# How to prove a function of two variables is non-continuous?

Tags: limits, continuity

$Let\;u(x,y)=\frac{1-(x^2+y^2)}{(1-x)^2+y^2}\;\forall (x,y) \in \mathcal D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2: x^2+y^2 \lt 1 \}$

How can I prove that $u\notin \mathcal C(\bar D)$ since I don't know the value of $u$ at $(1,0)$?

Could somebody give me a hint or help? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you let $y$ be 0 as $x$ goes to 1 , what would the limit be?

Comment: @AggelosBessis it would be equal to $\frac{2}{0}$ and so the limit does not exist?

Comment: Exactly, it cannot be continuous since we found a way to approach $(1,0)$ so that the limit doesn't exist!

Comment: @AggelosBessis Well it was that simple... I don't know why I had been stuck! Thank you a lot!!